# Heap Space Question

Tags: apex, limits, heap, heapsizelimit

I have a system.debug() that outputs the result of division of the currently used heap space by an integer. It always shows 0.

What could be the root cause of this?

Comment: Can you post an actual code? I assume problem is in division of integer numbers, so a/b would be always 0 if a < b, and they are both positive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An integer divided by an integer results in an integer, where the fractional part will be discarded. You must convert one of the integer values to a Decimal to get the correct result.

```
System.debug(3/2); // Outputs 1
System.debug(3.0/2); // Outputs 1.5
```

To get the correct "percentage" usage of heap, you need to make one of the values a decimal:

```
System.debug(Limits.getHeapSize()/Decimal.valueOf(Limits.getLimitHeapSize()));
```

Note that heap is tracked in all orgs (even sandboxes), but it does **not** automatically trigger the millisecond you hit the heap limit (e.g. 6,000,000). For example, the following code **will** result in an error in any org:

```
String[] heap = new String[0];
for(Integer i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
    heap.add('0'.repeat(i*100));
}
```

Contrariwise, this code should **never** throw an exception in any org (even production):

```
String a = '0'.repeat(6000000);
String b = '1'.repeat(6000000);
System.debug(Limits.getHeapSize()); // Outputs at least 12,000,000...
```

Also, there's some situations where the heap is temporarily tucked away, such as during nested triggers. I go in to a lot more detail in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/213675/2984), which I suggest you also take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on production or sandbox? According to this [link](http://www.fishofprey.com/2012/02/salesforce-limitexception-apex-heap.html), heap size is not tracked by the sandbox environment.

> Use Limits to check the values in Apex:

```
System.debug(LoggingLevel.Debug, 'Heap Size: ' + Limits.getHeapSize() + '/' + Limits.getLimitHeapSize());
```

> 09:43:04:672 USER_DEBUG [155]|DEBUG| Heap Size: 8877586/6000000 Note
>   how the actual Heap Size reported here is greater than the Heap Limit
>   size! This seems to be an oddity of the sandbox environment as in
>   production a LimitException would occur.

Comment: That blog post is incorrect (and thus, this answer is also incorrect). The heap limits are only checked "periodically", and you can exceed this limit for a small period of time. I've managed to hit 138,000,000 bytes of heap used without an exception occurring--in production. It's a lot more complicated than just checking every time there's a heap allocation.

Comment: Thanks for the correction and the detailed answer @sfdcfox.